# Input text overlaps inside button

Tags: css

I have a text type input, and a + button in the right side of it, the way I did this:

```
//html

<div class="input-wrapper">
    <input type="email">
  <button mat-icon-button>
    <mat-icon matSuffix>add_circle_outline</mat-icon>
  </button>
</div>

//css
.input-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0 25px;

  button {
    margin-left: -50px;
    margin-top: 17px;

    mat-icon {
      font-size: 24px;
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is , when the text in the input is too long it overlaps the button,is there any way to fix this without moving the button outside of the input?

Image below..

[image]

Comment: You can make the button not have a transparent background, you can give it padding as well.

Comment: @Yong adding padding doesn't fix the issue

Comment: Did you first give it a `background-color`? In this case, it's better to go with white/`#fff`.

Comment: @Yong , yes, the text simply goes below it https://imgur.com/a/Ensr0Zo , I want the text to stop before the button

Comment: You can just adjust the padding-right of your `input` if that's the case.

Comment: @Yong , the problem here is that I would need a negative padding, which does not exist, so this doesn't work also

Comment: You don't need a negative padding. Anyway made a sample snippet for your reference.

Comment: Maybe `float:right` solves this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Give a background to your `button` and `padding-right` to your input. See the snippet below:

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

button{
  border: none;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  left: -22px;
}

input{
  padding-right: 20px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css" integrity="sha384-ejwKkLla8gPP8t2u0eQyL0Q/4ItcnyveF505U0NIobD/SMsNyXrLti6CWaD0L52l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div>
  <input type="email">
  <button>
    <i class="bi bi-plus-circle"></i>
  </button>
</div>
```